# How to use i18n on angular component library

Tags: javascript, angular, internationalization

I use i18n on my own component library, but it's not working

in my module

```
// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [myLibraryModuleComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  exports: [myLibraryModuleComponent, TranslateModule]
})
export class myLibraryModule { }
```

I got

```
http://localhost:4200/assets/i18n/en.json
```

not found. It's not the good path

Answer (score 0):

Are you using aot?
if yes, as per the documentation, you must use an exported function instead of an inline function

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
```

Notice the `createTranslateLoader` between the parenthesis.

if no, try this:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

Comment: Hello i try your solutions but still not working, same error